# Issue in Synchronising Contacts

Tags: audience-manager

I have two contacts :
In Audience Manager DB, its showing 2069(test1 user) and 2070(test2 user) ids for these two contacts while in Subscription DB its showing 2070(test1 user) and 2071(test2 user) for the same contacts.
When I am trying to change the profile of test2 user(2070 of AM DB) from website, its showing me information of test1 user(2069 of AM DB) which is wrong.
How can I resolve the same, Sync service is already running.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the database IDs will not match across the two databases. 
That is perfectly normal.

What matters is the identification key(s) that you provide. They should be the same on both sides. If your problem is that they are not, you have a serious problem that we are unlikely to be able to solve through this site; you'll need to contact customer support.

If the problem is just with misunderstanding the identification of Contacts? 
Well, hopefully you are now the wiser :)

Comment: Contact_ID field in CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS is having different values in both the DBs.

Comment: As mentioned, that is perfectly normal. How are you loading the Contacts? If you used the sample pages as a starting point, you should be loading the contacts using the identification keys - which will match on both sides.

Comment: I need to pick the contact using TCMID of the contact in one of the scenario so I am using something like Contact.GetFromContactIdentificatonKeys(new string[] { Context.User.Identity.Name }) and  Contact.GetFromInternalContactId(TCMURI); in second case I am getting the wrong user because of Contact_ID differences in DBs

Comment: Indeed that will not work. You should use the identification keys to read the correct Contact. You cannot expect the same URI on CD and CM - that's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am not using Contact URI now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a running AM setup to check right now, but I think that the IDs in the subscription management database do not necessarily match those in the CM side database.

The reason for this is that contacts can be created both on back and front ends so trying to have a unique single column index for both would be impractical, especially as you could have multiple front-end databases.

You need to identify which columns identify a contact uniquely as defined in the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-E1627A09-CAA5-4279-8B48-C9FDC092C82C&addHistory=true&query=contact%2520unique&scope=&tid=58a8bd28-47ca-4a7c-98f1-99f8fc1dd9b2&filename=GUID-E1627A09-CAA5-4279-8B48-C9FDC092C82C.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-E1627A09-CAA5-4279-8B48-C9FDC092C82C&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=contact%2520unique&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1395317123667&currentQuery=contact%2520unique&currentScope=) [login required]. The sync process probably uses those to sync, rather than IDs.

Comment: Contact_ID field in CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS is having different values in both the DBs.